# LaTeX or TeXstudio creating a bunch of files for each compilation

Tags: compiling, auxiliary-files

I just got a new laptop and I installed the TeX Live installation of LaTeX. My favorite editor is TeXstudio so I downloaded that as well.
I spent a day working on a document and compiled it a bunch of times. When I subsequently checked the working directory, I found that a lot of files had been created. These files end up as, for example, "NAME".tex.AFi688, "NAME".tex.ALw688, etc... with every compilation creating a new set of files with a different, but similar, file extension.

In the start of my document I have the line "%& -aux-directory=AuxOut", which should take care of the auxiliary files, but upon closer inspection, the auxiliary files don't appear in in this directory, but rather in the directory that contains the source file itself.

This is not a problem when compiling on my desktop computer, so it might be that some of my settings are different on my laptop, but I am unable to identify which settings to modify.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thank you

Comment: @Darkyl Rough guess, do you compile the files that are in Dropbox?

Comment: Yes... Yes I do.
But I did this through my desktop computer as well, so should this matter?

Comment: Thank you, Raaja! This seems to be similar to what is happening to me. I will check it out and see if I can fix it. Thank you